# Pandas iterating over two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I have two Dataframes first one has my main data. I am taking one of the columns from the first dataframe and making another dataframe with string split.

```
_t1 = df1["TABLE_NAME"].str.split("_",expand = True)
_t1.head()
```

first value from the df1 is `T_STG_PRG_POS_NORM_FAREAST`and second is `T_STG_PRG_POS_NORM_EXEC_DBIT`

`_t1 looks like:`

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+------+---------+------+------+
| 0 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4   |    5    |  6   |  7   |
+---+-----+-----+-----+------+---------+------+------+
| T | STG | PRG | POS | NORM | FAREAST | None |      |
| T | STG | PRG | POS | NORM | EXCEC   | DBIT | None |
+---+-----+-----+-----+------+---------+------+------+
```

now I want to create a column `df1["SYSTEM NAME"]` which should have values `FAREAST` for row 0 and `DBIT`

I am trying this loop:

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    for column in _t1:
        if (pd.isna(_t1[column][row])== True):
            df1["SYSTEM NAME"]= _t1[column-1][row]
```

But I am getting an error: `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`

Comment: can you try with `df1["SYSTEM NAME"]=df1["TABLE_NAME"].str.split("_").str[5]` ?

Comment: @anky_91 that works row 0 but will not work for other rows. There will be total 7 columns in _t1 and any from 5-7 could be final values.

Comment: So you want the final valid value of each `_t1` row?

Comment: @Valentino the value in `df1["SYSTEM NAME"]` should be the last non-None value from each row of `_t1`

Comment: There is no column 7 in your example.

Comment: @rpanai columns are 0-7 in _t1 ....its the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need `t1` as you are looking for the last element of your split. The following should work and it's vectorial.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TABLE_NAME":["T_STG_PRG_POS_NORM_FAREAST",
                                 "T_STG_PRG_POS_NORM_EXEC_DBIT"]})

df["SYSTEM_NAME"] = df["TABLE_NAME"].str.split("_").str[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As for [@rpanai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57675064/10426037), you don't need `_t1`.

But in case you want for some reason use `_t1`, here is how to do:

```
df1['SYSTEM_NAME'] = _t1.apply(lambda x : x[x.notna()].iloc[-1], axis=1)
```

The `lambda` function in the apply method gets the last non NA element from each row.
`None` and `np.Nan` values are both considered NA values by [notna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html#pandas.DataFrame.notna).